# Is there any way to form the Odata filter like $filter=Emails/any(s: s eq 'somestring') using Breeze library?

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

For example I have a model structure like the following:

```
{
"@odata.context": "serviceRoot/$metadata#People",
"@odata.nextLink": "serviceRoot/People?%24skiptoken=8",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.id": "serviceRoot/People('russellwhyte')",
        "Emails": [ "Russell@example.com", "Russell@contoso.com" ]
    }, 
    ...
    ]
}
```

And I want to query all People who have "Russell@contoso.com" email in theirs email list. (Notice that the *Emails* is a collection of primitive type string.)

It seems like Breeze can only do smth like this, when dealing with collection of complex objects:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("People")
.where("Email", "any", "fldname",  "eq", "Russell@contoso.com");
```

Here "fldname" is a field that supposed to be inside the Email type.

But what if I want to compare primitive type like String and I don't have any field inside? In this case OData query would looks like the following:

```
$filter=Emails/any(s: s eq 'Russell@contoso.com')
```

But is there any way to form this query using Breeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, you can't compose it with the breeze query language which, AFAIK, doesn't understand filtering on a property that returns an array of strings.

But YES, you can send *any* URL to the server with a breeze query. If you can manually construct a URL that your OData server will interpret appropriately, go right ahead and send it.

```
var qUrl = "People/?$filter=Emails/any(s: s eq 'Russell@contoso.com')";
var q = breeze.EntityQuery.from(qUrl);
manager.executeQuery(q).then(...).catch(...);
```